# Prevent line break between an inline element and period

Tags: html, css

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/w6nx64d8/3/).

As you can see, I made the `<button>` element `inline` (in fact, doesn't matter if it's `inline` or `inline-block`).

The issue is that on some certain container width, the "." goes to the next line by itself, which is weird.

Without the button element, "here" and "." goes to the next line together, which is the desired behavior.

I don't want to place an explicit line break before "here". It should be responsive. Meaning, if the container is wide enough, everything should go in one line.

I also don't want to put the "." inside the button because it should not be colored.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I don't know the reason for this and can't find a nice solution currently. You can force the button and the dot to be in the same line by wrapping them in a span, though: `<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><button>here</button>.</span>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the button and period in a container with `white-space: nowrap`:

```
<p >This section means lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. You can see the permissions <span style="white-space: nowrap;"><button>here</button>.</span></p>
```

(Although I would always use a class rather than in-line style in practice).

Comment: If using Bootstrap 4, a `<span class="text-nowrap">...</span>` does the same thing. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow

Answer (score 1):

If you place the button and the period inside a new container with `display: inline-block`, the browser will prefer to keep them on the same line. Wrapping will occur before or after the new container as long as it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The most correct element to use would be an `<a>` element - since you are expecting the user to click it and then go to that location and see the result.

Since `<a>`'s are already inline elements - this will not affect your layout. You can style the `a` to look any way you want - but this is not the job of a button. It is always best to use the right tool for the job.

```css
p{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
}

a {
  color:red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>This section means lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. You can see the permissions <a href="target-location.html">here</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The `a` element has the same issue. Doesn't matter which element it is, as long as an inline element. See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/w6nx64d8/5/

Comment: Actually the issue that drops that to the next line is the width constraint on the div. Just try adding or removing content from your sample text or increase the 508px to say 60px and you will see that it is simply word wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo class instead of having the "." as part of text itself. Here is the code that works
From your example, remove the "." from the HTML and add the button:after in the css

HTML:

```
<div style="width:508px">
<p >This section means lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. You can see the permissions <button>
here</button></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p{
font-size: 14px;
font-family: arial;
}
button {  
border: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 14px;
height: auto;
display: inline;
color: red;
}
button::after{
content:'.';
color: black;
}
```

Comment: Good thinking. But "." shouldn't go with the button though.

Comment: @Shawn - I thought you wanted the button and . to go together ? Can you explain what’s the behavior you expect?